# How to efficiently generate a random safe prime of given length?

Tags: rsa, prime-numbers, safe-prime

A prime $p$ is said to be safe prime if $(p-1)/2$ is also a prime. How to efficiently generate a safe prime? I have written the following code in sagemath which generates a random safe prime of 1536 bits. This code took 426 seconds to generate a safe prime. That's very inefficient. Is there a faster way to efficiently generate a safe prime?

```
while True:
    p = random_prime(2^1536-1, false, 2^(1535))
    if ZZ((p-1)/2).is_prime():
        return p
```

Comment: Recently asked before. Generate prime $q$ then check $2q+1$ is a prime.

Comment: "*Safe primes are heavily used in constructing RSA modulus*". Could you provide a link to this reasoning? As of now it should suffice to use a cryptographically strong random number generator, which has been properly seeded with adequate entropy, to generate the primes $p$ and $q$.

Comment: @AleksanderRas To stop this attack https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_p_%E2%88%92_1_algorithm

Comment: @satya Yes, but there it also says "*Most sufficiently large primes are strong*", so you can use an already optimized RSA-generator for efficiency.

Comment: Also see [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/47733/23623) for more reasoning on why safe primes are unneccessary for RSA.

Comment: For my scheme built from RSA assumption, I need to have the following property: "Every" prime factor of $\phi(N)$ other than 2 should be large. So, I was planning to use safe primes for that purpose.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no more efficient way of generating a safe prime. Even in OpenSSL's optimized code, it can take a long time to generate a safe prime (30 seconds, a minute, 2 minutes). Run "openssl gendh 1024" on your computer to see (on my 2015 MacBook pro it can take a long time, but the variance is really high so try a few times).

The comments talk about safe primes for RSA. Indeed, safe primes are *not* needed for RSA. However, they are needed for generating parameters for finite-field cryptography (Diffie-Hellman over a finite field), and for other applications in cryptography. For example, zero-knowledge range proofs use a group with an unknown order, and this is defined by an RSA modulus and Pedersen commitments over that modulus. When using safe primes, this ensures that the group is large and furthermore that a random group element is a generator with overwhelming probability. See Section 1.2 of [Efficient Protocols for Set Membership and Range Proofs](https://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/128718/files/CCS08.pdf) for more about this particular application.

So, in more advanced cryptography, there are plenty of applications for safe primes (indeed, RSA encryption is not one of them).

Comment: note: gendh no longer works in the new openssl as in the answer. The [newer version](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/dhparam.html) has  `dhparam`. So call is `openssl dhparam 1028`. In my computer the time is `real    0m1,568s` with i5-8250U

Comment: When I enter "openssl gendh 1024" command, the first line of output says "Generating DH parameters, 1024 bit long safe prime, generator 2". What does "generator 2" mean?

Comment: Minor nitpick - OpenSSL actually finds a prime q and then checks if 2q+1 is prime, which is slightly more efficient than what OP suggests since you’re checking smaller numbers for primality in the initial prime check.

Comment: @satya https://security.stackexchange.com/a/54367/165253

Comment: DH doesn't require 'safe', it is sufficient if |$Z_p^*$|=p-1 has _a_ large enough prime factor and we choose a subgroup of that order. In fact you can use a Schnorr group like for DSA p=kq+1 with e.g. |p|=2048 |q|=224 and `openssl dsaparam $bits | openssl dhparam -dsaparam` _or_ simpler `openssl dhparam -dsaparam $bits` does exactly that, much faster. Java crypto, at least with the SunJCE provider for `KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("DH")`, does the same. @satya: DH works in a subgroup of $Z_p^*$ 'generated' by taking powers of a fixed element called the generator or base, notated 'g'.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Safe is a special case with $k=2$. In general, I feel less comfortable with using these Schnorr-like groups for Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange. Note that Schnorr relies on discrete log only, where DH relies on the DDH assumption. Not that any attacks are known, but...

Answer (score 6):

You can speed up the generation of safe primes by sieving for $p$ and $(p-1)/2$ simultanously. According to [Safe prime generation with a combined sieve](https://ia.cr/2003/186) by Michael J. Wiener sieving small primes up to $2^{16}$ this way is about 15x faster than the naive algorithm.

Be aware that the running time for finding a prime has a huge variation, so just measuring once and saying "it takes 426s" doesn't say much (average time could easily be a magnitude lower or higher).