# What are the safe primes for $p$ and $q$ ​used in ElGamal?

Tags: elgamal-encryption, key-generation, safe-prime

I need to generate a 2048 bit key for ElGamal and I was looking for the $p$ and $q$ for PGP but I couldn't find them. the only thing I could find was this [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5114) but those are not safe primes.

Does anyone know where I can find those numbers?

Comment: select a uniform random prime, then multiply by 2 and add 1, finally test it for primeness, if not return the begin else, done.

Comment: Does this question help you [How to efficiently generate a random safe prime of given length?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/66076/18298), or this [Efficient algorithm for finding Sophie Germain primes](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/60329/18298). Both are in the safe-prime tag.

Comment: it takes too long to generate a key of that size
in a web client

Comment: What is too long, what is short, what are the capabilities of the web client, etc...Isn't it a one time generation?

Comment: In the project I am working on every time a user logs in, a new key is generated. Therefore, it will be frustrating for a user to wait so long each time they go to the login page.

Comment: You still did not talk about the too long. One needs to provide numbers, right? Your long my short.

Comment: Jolo - unless the keys are generated at the client side, maybe you can pre-prepare a pool of these keys and give the key to the user at login?

Comment: You don't need to generate a fresh group for each new key; the primes $p$ and $q$ need to be computed only once.  If you're looking for some precomputed values, there is RFC3526 and RFC7919 appendix A, which both list only safe primes (hence $q = (p-1)/2$)

Comment: @Jolo could you answer your question?